# Examples of minimum browser support for Compass 1.x

Tags: sass, compass-sass

Has anyone mananged to get browser support working in Compass Alpha.
I'm on version alpha19 and tried adding the following to the top of my SASS file

```
$browser-minimum-versions: (
  "chrome":  "35",
  "firefox": "28",
  "ie":      "9",
  "safari":  "6",
  "opera":   "20"
);
```

When I run this I still saw * star hacks in one of the compass mixins I used (inline-block). On looking at the source for inline-block it only outputs star hacks for ie7 but having set my min version support to ie9 it should not have done this.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you are misinterpreting – like I did – how the minimum versions work.
Chris Eppstein explains it in a [related issue on github](https://github.com/Compass/compass/pull/1524#issuecomment-51499351):

> The minimum browser versions list does not exclude browsers, it includes browsers that would have otherwise been excluded by the threshold. If you want to exclude some version of IE, just adjust your threshold higher than the % of users using that version and below. If that excludes some other browsers that you don't want to exclude you add them to the minimum browser list. the logic is an OR between the threshold and the minimum support... not an AND.